# Change product URL id to product name in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

This is my url

```
localhost:8080/products/62567252370e769a8a93a517
```

This is my product object

```json
{
    "_id": "62567252370e769a8a93a517",
    "category": {
        "_id": "62566ec30e42d6c5ab370e7c",
        "products": [],
        "type": "mobile phone",
        "__v": 0
    },
    "title": "galaxy s10",
}
```

This is my route

```js
path: "/products/:id",
name: "Product",
component: Product
```

Please how can I replace `product._id` in my url with the `{{product.title}}`

For example
I want the url to be like this

```
localhost:8080/products/galaxys10
```

Please how can I go about this

Answer (score 0):

Given that the `title` in your data object contains spaces, you'd have to use a [computed prop](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) that returns the title without the spaces:

```js
// MyComponent.vue
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      product: {
        title: 'galaxy s10',
        ⋮
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    productTitle() {
      return this.product.title.replace(/\s+/g, '') // remove spaces from title
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can bind that `productTitle` computed prop to the [`<router-link>`](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link)'s URL, using the [`v-bind` directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind):

```html
<!-- MyComponent.vue -->
<router-link :to="`/products/${productTitle}`">Galaxy S10</router-link>
```

...or you can push the URL programatically with [`this.$router.push()`](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-push-location-oncomplete-onabort):

```js
// MyComponent.vue
export default {
  methods: {
    gotoProductPage() {
      this.$router.push('/products/' + this.productTitle)
    }
  }
}
```